# How does one plot values in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two lines (one for the revenue and the other for earnings) on a matplotlib chart. Unfortunately I am having a problem doing so. I get an error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Here is the dictionary data:

```
[{'date': '2Q2019', 'revenue': 53809000000, 'earnings': 10044000000}, {'date': '3Q2019', 'revenue': 64040000000, 'earnings': 13686000000}, {'date': '4Q2019', 'revenue': 91819000000, 'earnings': 22236000000}, {'date': '1Q2020', 'revenue': 58313000000, 'earnings': 11249000000}]
```

And here is my code:

```
quarterlyfinaincalEarnings =[{'date': 2016, 'revenue': 215639000000, 'earnings': 45687000000}, {'date': 2017, 'revenue': 229234000000, 'earnings': 48351000000}, {'date': 2018, 'revenue': 265595000000, 'earnings': 59531000000}, {'date': 2019, 'revenue': 260174000000, 'earnings': 55256000000}]

names = list(quarterlyfinaincalEarnings.keys())
values = list(quarterlyfinaincalEarnings.values())

plt.bar(range(len(quarterlyfinaincalEarnings)),values,tick_label=names)
plt.show()
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `pandas`

- Your data is a `list` of `dicts`
- Convert your data to a dataframe, then plot it

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
data = [{'date': '2Q2019', 'revenue': 53809000000, 'earnings': 10044000000},
        {'date': '3Q2019', 'revenue': 64040000000, 'earnings': 13686000000},
        {'date': '4Q2019', 'revenue': 91819000000, 'earnings': 22236000000},
        {'date': '1Q2020', 'revenue': 58313000000, 'earnings': 11249000000}]

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# split date into quarters and years
df['quarter'], df['year'] = df.date.str[:2], df.date.str[-4:]

print(df)

   date      revenue     earnings quarter  year
 2Q2019  53809000000  10044000000      2Q  2019
 3Q2019  64040000000  13686000000      3Q  2019
 4Q2019  91819000000  22236000000      4Q  2019
 1Q2020  58313000000  11249000000      1Q  2020

# plot the dataframe
df.plot('year', ['revenue', 'earnings'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah yes.. this is it! Thanks mate

Comment: @AndrewRoj as a note, the answer in your other question isn't needed now, because year is already a string, in this case.  However, as a general case, if your column is only numeric, it will probably be interpreted as an int or float.

Answer (score 1):

```
#use print statements to understand the type of variables

aa=[{'date': '2Q2019', 'revenue': 53809000000, 'earnings': 10044000000}, 
    {'date': '3Q2019', 'revenue': 64040000000, 'earnings': 13686000000}, 
    {'date': '4Q2019', 'revenue': 91819000000, 'earnings': 22236000000}, 
    {'date': '1Q2020', 'revenue': 58313000000, 'earnings': 11249000000}]
print(type(aa))

for a in aa:
    print(type(a))
    print(a, a['date'],a['revenue'],a['earnings'])
```

output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'dict'>
{'date': '2Q2019', 'revenue': 53809000000, 'earnings': 10044000000} 2Q2019 53809000000 10044000000
<class 'dict'>
{'date': '3Q2019', 'revenue': 64040000000, 'earnings': 13686000000} 3Q2019 64040000000 13686000000
<class 'dict'>
{'date': '4Q2019', 'revenue': 91819000000, 'earnings': 22236000000} 4Q2019 91819000000 22236000000
<class 'dict'>
{'date': '1Q2020', 'revenue': 58313000000, 'earnings': 11249000000} 1Q2020 58313000000 11249000000
```

plotting

```
aa=[{'date': '2Q2019', 'revenue': 53809000000, 'earnings': 10044000000}, 
{'date': '3Q2019', 'revenue': 64040000000, 'earnings': 13686000000}, 
{'date': '4Q2019', 'revenue': 91819000000, 'earnings': 22236000000}, 
{'date': '1Q2020', 'revenue': 58313000000, 'earnings': 11249000000}]


dates,revs,earns=[],[],[]  
for a in aa:
    dates.append(a['date'])
    revs.append(a['revenue'])
    earns.append(a['earnings'])



import matplotlib.pyplot as p
p.plot(dates,revs,label='revenues')
p.plot(dates,earns,label='earnings')
p.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: hey mate thanks for the response. I was trying to plot those two line charts on one graph. like one line for earnings and the other for revenue.